# How to set the 'targets' dynamically in columnDefs dataTable.js

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am generating the `dataTable` from `xml` data. I want to change the column visibility based upon the column name. I Do not want to hard code the value for `targets` like 2 or 3 and also I do not want to set based on the class name.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var dataOptions = {
    {
      "columnDefs": [ {
         "visible": false,
         "targets":2
     } ]
    }

   };
   $('#example').dataTable( dataOptions );
} );

#Edit
My XML DATA
  <root>
    <filterStartDate>2006-11-18</filterStartDate>
    <filterEndDate>2015-02-11</filterEndDate>
    <responseCount>0</responseCount>
    <responseCountFormatted></responseCountFormatted>
    <metadata>
     <columns>
        <column name="startDate" type="DATE" nameT="Start Date" sortable="true" />
        <column name="endDate" type="DATE" nameT="End Date" sortable="true" />
        <column name="COMPANY_ID" type="STRING" nameT="Company" sortable="true" />
        <column name="COMPANY_ID___code" type="STRING" nameT="Company" visible="false" />
        <column name="multipleGroupBy" type="STRING" nameT="Multiple Group By" visible="false" />
     </columns>
    </metadata>
    <pageInformation><totalPages>1</totalPages><totalRows>10</totalRows><pageStart>0</pageStart><pageEnd>10</pageEnd><rowsPerPage>50</rowsPerPage></pageInformation>
    <data>
       <row startDate="2006-11-18" endDate="2015-02-11" COMPANY_ID="CONSUMER" COMPANY_ID___code="CONSUMER" multipleGroupBy="|CONSUMER">
       </row>
    </data>
   </root>
```

Can I achieve this in a better way...

Comment: take all the columns names in a array. And print the index for each column  in the  "targets"

Comment: How does the XML look like?

Comment: @davidkonrad I changed the post by adding the response xml.

Answer (score 1):

Looks straight forward to me, like the XML is generated specifically to dataTables or is based on a dataTables instance itself. When you wrote "*I want to change the column visibility based upon the column name*" I guess you mean the column attribute `visible`?

```
var parser = new DOMParser(),
    doc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "application/xml"),
    columns = doc.querySelectorAll('column'),
    options = { columnDefs:[] },
    column;

for (var i=0;i<columns.length;i++) {
    column = columns[i];
    options.columnDefs.push({ 
        data : column.getAttribute('name'),
        title : column.getAttribute('nameT'),        
        type : column.getAttribute('type'),        
        visible : column.getAttribute('visible') == 'false' ? false : true,        
        sortable : column.getAttribute('sortable'),        
        targets : i
    });
}

var table = $('#example').DataTable(options);
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/pbtb8h42/**  Sorry if I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

**You just need to change the value of i dynamically**

define the **var i = 2;** and assign this **i** value to **"targets":i** and then **change value of i as you want**